# JSON-B hitting NPE serializing with adapter though setting withNullValues(true)

Tags: java, json, jsonb-api

### Problem

The JSON-B user guide suggests [here](http://json-b.net/docs/user-guide.html#null-handling) that I should be able to serialize `null` values with my code of:

```
    Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create(new JsonbConfig()
            .withNullValues(true)
            .withAdapters(new StatusAdapter()));

    jsonb.toJson(status,Status.class);
```

Here **StatusAdapter** is my own **JsonbAdapter** impl to serialize the app's **Status** class and looks something like this:

#### StatusAdapter

```
@Override
public JsonObject adaptToJson(Status status) throws Exception {

   // ... 

   return Json.createObjectBuilder()

            .add("field1", status.getField1())               
            .add("field2", status.getField2())               

             // ... continues ...

            .build();
```

But when one of these getters returns `null`, I end up getting exceptions like:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Value in JsonObjects
>   name/value pair cannot be null
>           at org.glassfish.json.JsonObjectBuilderImpl.validateValue(JsonObjectBuilderImpl.java:222)
>           at org.glassfish.json.JsonObjectBuilderImpl.add(JsonObjectBuilderImpl.java:90)
>           at mypkg.StatusAdapter.adaptToJson(StatusAdapter.java:47)
>           at mypkg.StatusAdapter.adaptToJson(StatusAdapter.java:14)
>           at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AdaptedObjectSerializer.serialize(AdaptedObjectSerializer.java:103)

### pom.xml

I used the *latest versions* of the Maven dependencies from the JSON-B [Getting Started](http://json-b.net/getting-started.html) page:

```
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.json.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.json.bind-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
                    <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.3</version>
            </dependency>
```

### Question

So am I misunderstanding the API?  Or is this an incorrect combination of JSON-related libraries?  A bug in one of them?

I realize too, that serializing a `null` might leave me with a second problem when it's time to deserialize it.  I am going to want to use JSON-B to deserialize later, if that helps guide the answer.  Thank you.

#### Update:

This [yasson issue](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/yasson/issues/135) suggests it might be a bug.   Added more detail there.

Comment: Are you telling Jsonb that the fields you're trying to use can be null? Cause setting the building to allow null values doesn't mean that it'll allow null values I would assume. Just by the docs alone, I would assume that you'd need to use the annotations shown in the docs. Have you done so?

Comment: No, I would have tried class/package/field annotations on objects I developed from source but this is an external class, which is why I'm using the adapter to begin with.

Comment: While referenced yasson issue is actually a bug, it is not related to the issue in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception which you get is basically telling you that you can't pass a null into JsonObjectBuilder#add method, which is thrown by JSONP implementation `org.glassfish:javax.json`.

Setting `JsonbConfig#withNullValues(true)` does not relate to it.

JSONB and JSONP are two different APIs, even so JSONB does depend on JSONP. `org.eclipse:yasson` is an implementation of JSONB API which in your case does use `org.glassfish:javax.json` - an implementation of JSONP API, because you provided it in your POM.

Setting `JsonbConfig#withNullValues(true)` is a call on JSONB API which does mean *"print null values to JSON"* for example:

`{
  firstname: null,
  lastname: null
}`

So when `org.eclipse:yasson` (JSONB) encounters a null value in a pojo object property it does something like `javax.json.stream.JsonGenerator#writeNull(key)`.

This does not relate in any way to your code in `StatusAdapter` which is basically calling JSONP API `JsonObjectBuilder#add` with a null value, which is not allowed.

Comment: Thank you Roman for explaining.   In stepping through the code, it didn't feel like a bug, and I was guessing I was misunderstanding the relationship btw. JSONB and JSONP here.